# How to disable the Denial Log Reporting Service on SGS4?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4

On my Samsung Galaxy S4 I've accidentally accepted a privacy policy for the "Samsung Denial Log Reporting Service" in a popped notification. I've found in Google that it "Captures SE for Android denials in Enforcement mode on the device and uploads them to a Samsung Server".

Does anyone know how to disable this <s>crap</s> option?

Comment: This as you may know is part of Samsung Knox. I had this same issue and never got an answer from Samsung so I rooted the phone and installed a Knox free ROM. Obviously that isn't for everyone. Can you open the Knox app? You should be able to disable this denial report logging from the settings.

Comment: @RossC No, I don't seem to be able to open the Knox app.. I have android 4.2.2, if that matters.

Comment: Ok, shot in the dark: Log out of your Samsung account, and log back in. It should (hopefully) ask this question again, select 'do not show for 30 days' and cancel the request! Let me know if it works, I'll keep looking. I can't test it here as I have a knox free ROM!

Comment: @RossC I've tried relogging into Samsung account, no question so far.

Comment: Samsung Knox is a thorn in my side. It's negatively affecting the dev community and this kind of thing is not helping. You may be stuck with this reporting going on. The only things I can think of left are go into Settings > More > Appliction Manager and try to disable anything Knox related. I doubt this will work. You could root the phone but this WILL trip the Knox counter to 0x1 and MAY have warranty implications, install a knox free ROM. You could wait to see if logging in has affected it, reboot and see. Failing that welcome to the wonderful world of locked bootloaders and 'helpful' Knox.

Comment: If you hit the menu button on your home screen is there a 'Knox Settins' option? I doubt it in 4.4.2 though. Are you due an update to 4.3?

Comment: @RossC Nope, no such option there. I guess I'm recieving the 4.3 update soon. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You could do a factory reset, but I have seen conflicting reports on whether this actually works or not. Sorry about this, Knox is a major issue for everyone at the moment. Rooting is the most direct way to kill knox where it stands, but it's not necessarily the best route for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You need to root your phone and remove or "freeze" everything related to OTA and KNOX. Once done, you can remove the all AVC audit file(s) in the directory: `/data/misc/audit/`. You may also need to put SEAndroid into *Permissive* mode with: `su 0 setenforce 0`, but this only lasts until next reboot.